# Google Maps and FancyBox, odd resize

Tags: google-maps, resize, fancybox

I have been digging and searching for answer through the board but can't quite get it.
I am geocoding an address and displaying the map in a FancyBox.
Example:

```
   http://76.12.196.238/~oregon/solarPledge1.html
```

Just click the Check Map link to activate the code. I will eventually push the contents of the form but for now am pushing a hard coded address just to  test.
So it works fine if I DO NOT hide the div containing the map and being called by fancybox and have it appear on the page. If I DO hide the div (which I have to for the sake of the program) it does not render correctly when it opens in Fancy Box. It shows only about half the map... the rest is grey. Now if I barely resize the browser window it then corrects itself and displays correctly.

I am sure it is a resize of the map, but I am trying it different places and no results. I currently have it in the fancybox call

```
   'onComplete': function(){
     checkResize();
},
```

You can see the code at the bottom of the page on the call of fancybox. The mapping.js was taken from Google Maps. It is clearly an issue with the FancyBox but can't figure out where!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904495/1055987 if that helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery FancyBox with Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890948/jquery-fancybox-with-google-maps)