# How do I force redraw with Google Maps API v3.0?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-animate

I have a fairly sophisticated Maps application that handles multiple custom markers and such. I have a function called resizeWindow that I call in a listener to that whenever the screen is changed, the map redraws itself by calculating new bounds and forcing a resize. It looks like this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) { fitmap(); };
```

and the function to resize is:

```
function fitmap(id) {
    var coords = [];
    var newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(projlat, projlng);
    coords.push(newlatlng);

        for (var i=0; i<markers[id].length; i++) {
            newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[id][i].latitude, markers[id][i].longitude);
            coords.push(newlatlng);
        }
    }   

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = coords.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
        bounds.extend (coords[i]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

and this works great when I actually resize the window. But...

I have a menu going down the right side of the window. I use jquery.animate to move that menu off the screen. I call the fitmap function as a step process (or just once at the end) and it will not redraw the map.

```
$('#rightSide').animate({ right:"-240px" }, { 
    duration:1000, 
    step: function(now,fx) {
        fitmap();
    } 
});
```

I have read and read on this and it seems that there is an oddity of Google Maps API v3.0 that redrawing will not happen if nothing actually changes. In this case, my available window does change from screen width - menu to actual full screen. But no redraw happens.

I've tried google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); and that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to absolutely force Google Maps to redraw?

Comment: Can you give us a link?

Comment: There is a little tab on the top left side of the right-side menu.

Comment: Also, if you have your browser window set to a size that this change forces a zoom change, then it works. It is only when no zoom change is necessary that it won't adjust. I also tried forcing a 1-step zoom out and zoom back in but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to refresh the map, when window size has not changed!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`google.maps.event.trigger(MapInstance,'resize')` is working fine for me, put it at the begin of the function `fitMap` .

What you are missing:

currently(not in the code posted above, in your live-code), you call `resizeWindow` on each `step` .

When you call this function on `step` the function will be called **before** the animation for the current step has finished. The result is that `resizeWindow` will not be called when the complete animation has been finished, there will be e.g. a margin on the right side of the map.

Solution: call `resizeWindow` also on the `complete`-callback of the `animation`.

Comment: Ah. THanks! I had forgotten which copy of the code I put over there on test. I was trying all ways. But I didn't know the step function was called BEFORE the step.

Comment: This doesn't work for version 3.32 or greater. From this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743214/how-do-i-resize-a-google-map-with-javascript-after-it-has-loaded): With a new renderer release in version 3.32 of Maps JavaScript API the resize event is no longer a part of Map class.