# Ionic: New slides (Swiper) + angular-google-maps lead to grey space when dragging

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

When combining the new slides (aka Swiper) and angular-google-maps, dragging is not possible inside of Google Maps and leads to grey space instead.

This even happens when we disable swiping via .lockSwipes()

What I also unsuccessfully tried are these attributes:

```
onlyExternal: true
touchMoveStopPropagation: false
preventClicksPropagation: false
```

Finally, I found that using google.maps.event.trigger(MapInstance, 'resize') like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426083/how-do-i-force-redraw-with-google-maps-api-v3-0) does not work either.

This is my code:

```
<ion-slides options="swiper">
  <ion-slide-page>
    <ui-gmap-google-map control="map.control" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
  </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

and in my .js:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.swiper = {
    onInit: function(swiper){
      swiper.lockSwipes();
    }
  };
  $scope.map = { control:{}, center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
});
```

Here's a plunkr that shows my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/JiAw0oXRxLGgL3SrE6PK?p=preview2

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: No. I ended up changing my slides to divs with ng-show. Not a nice solution but at least my maps work again.

Answer (score 1):

After pulling my own hair out for two hours, the solution I finally found here worked for me:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-map-inside-ion-slides-display-issue/53743/2

The long and short is that the Swiper messes with the CSS underneath google maps. Since I am using ng-map, this line worked for me:

```
ng-map img { max-height: none !important; }
```