# Google maps infoWindow. Changed content via ajax is not kept after closing infoWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a number of markers displayed on a Google map. Markers are loaded from a dB and added to the array `markers`:

```
var markers = [
{
    "ID": "99",
    "title": "Ut vestibulum tincidunt consectetur vestibulum.",
    "coords": "45.6496292, 13.7740742",
},
{
    "ID": "259",
    "title": "Faucibus tempus vivamus scelerisque vestibulum.",
    "coords": "45.6455002, 13.7595193",
},
{
    "ID": "261",
    "title": "Taciti ante scelerisque consequat inceptos nunc.",
    "coords": "45.6455002, 13.7595193",
}
];
```

By clicking a marker *infoWindow* is popped up correctly:

```
gooole.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Inside *infoWindow* there's a link that when clicked pops up a boostrap dialog that permits to edit the content of *infoWindow*. The fields of this dialog are populated via Ajax (jQuery). When a field is changed and changes are saved, the dialog closes and the changed data is immediately shown in the *infoWindow* that in the meanwhile stayed opened.

Up to now everything works fine.

The issue I'm working on without success is that when I close the 'edited' *infoWindow* or I click on an other marker so that the 'edited' *infoWindow* closes and then I reopen the previous 'edited' *infoWindow* the changes are not shown.

I thought I could simply change the value in the `markers` array for example like this:

```
setTitle(id, "This is the new title");

function setTitle(id, newtitle) 
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i]["ID"] === id) {
            markers[i]["title"] = newtitle;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and see it 'react' dinamically in the *infoWindow* but it does not. The `markers` array is built in `index.php` while the map and the dialog are loaded via ajax separately (`map.php` and `edit.php`). I placed `markers` in `index.php` so I'm sure it is accessible and in fact for example

```
 console.log(markers[13]["title"]);
```

displays correctly any change, but this change is not 'preserved' to be shown in the 'edited' *infoWindow* .

Comment: i think you need to redraw the map, may be triggering a resize event will help `google.maps.event.trigger(MapInstance,'resize')` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426083/how-do-i-force-redraw-with-google-maps-api-v3-0

Comment: After clicking on a marker you set the content of info window as `infowindow.setContent(this.content);`. Do you update the value of `this.content` after saving the data?