# no view full map using ngmap and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I'm using ngmap and I presented the problem you see in the picture
[image]

My code:

```js
var app = angular.module('dv', ['ngMap'])

app.controller('MC', function($scope){
  
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
    });
  
})
```

```html
<body ng-app='dv' ng-controller='MC'>
<div map-lazy-load="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" id="map">
<map center="37.7699298, -122.4469157" zoom="12" style="width:100%;height:300px;">
<marker position="37.7699298, -122.4469157" title="Hello World!"></marker>
</map>
<div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-map shows partial map in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443918/ng-map-shows-partial-map-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Change any src scripts you are importing from ***http*** to ***https***
***Example***
**FROM** http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'
**TO** https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'
or https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js