# How to trigger the window resize event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onresize

I have registered a trigger on window resize. I want to know how I can trigger the event to be called. For example, when hide a div, I want my trigger function to be called.

I found `window.resizeTo()` can trigger the function, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 491, accepted):

Where possible, I prefer to call the function rather than dispatch an event. This works well if you have control over the code you want to run, but see below for cases where you don't own the code.

```
window.onresize = doALoadOfStuff;

function doALoadOfStuff() {
    //do a load of stuff
}
```

In this example, you can call the `doALoadOfStuff` function without dispatching an event.

In your modern browsers, you can [trigger the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) using:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

This doesn't work in Internet Explorer, where you'll have to do the longhand:

```
var resizeEvent = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
resizeEvent.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
```

[jQuery has the `trigger` method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), which works like this:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

And has the caveat:

> Although `.trigger()` simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

You can also simulate events on a specific element...

```
function simulateClick(id) {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });

  var elem = document.getElementById(id); 

  return elem.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Your anonymous function is unnecessary.

window.onresize = doALoadOfStuff;

Also, this doesn't answer the question, pinouchon's answer below is the correct answer.

Comment: To **Google**r's: Have a look at @avetisk's answer.

Comment: It's a good idea to decouple, but in my/this case, it doesn't work. Just calling the resize method doesn't work because if the window resize isn't triggered various other div/containers won't have the proper height set.

Comment: @PandaWood - then my last example is better in your case.

Comment: window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); causes an exception in latest Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'."

Comment: much obliged mate. this was really helpfull

Answer (score 845):

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: seems to work with Chrome, FF, Safari, but not: IE !

Comment: jQuery's `trigger` does not actually trigger the native "resize" event. It only triggers event listeners that have been added using jQuery. In my case, a 3rd party library was listening directly to the native "resize" event and this is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Great and simple solution. Although, I think you should add some code for IE compatibility (as far as I see, for IE, we have to use `window.fireEvent`)

Comment: this didnt work on all devices for me.
i had to trigger the event like this:
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);

Comment: Victor && @Manfred: please specify for which version of which browser(s), I'll quote your comments in my answer.

Comment: It fails with "Object doesn't support this action" in my IE11

Comment: Try Manfred's solution @pomber. It is the only one that worked for me for IE Edge and may work for IE11 as well.

Comment: Thanks @RobertWaddell, actually I've already done that and posted it as an answer here

Comment: I had to put this event in a `setTimeout` because it was likely getting fired too soon after the DOM manipulation that I was trying to get resized.

Comment: Anyidea why jquery $(window).trigger('resize') not working?

Comment: this worked good for me, better than $(window).trigger('resize')

Comment: Just to add, this did work for me but the jQuery version $(window).trigger('resize') did not. jQuery must do something slightly different.

Comment: This worked for me, where the jQuery version posted in other answers here didn't. So it seems the jQuery version isn't exactly the same

Comment: It's worth noting this is the only way to trigger all resize handlers (third party or not) while in most cases jQuery's  $(window).trigger('resize') will call resize event handlers created by jQuery itselt.

Comment: 'evt.initUIEvent' is deprecated as it is written in above comment by @Manfred

Answer (score 160):

With jQuery, you can try to call [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: A use case for this is when a jQuery plugin uses window resize events to be responsive, but you have a collapsing sidebar. The plugin's container gets resized, but the window does not.

Comment: No need for JQuery indeed but I prefer JQuery solution as my product uses JQuery extensively.

Comment: Where would this be added to resize a wordpress page after it has loaded?

Comment: This is not working for me in latest Chrome, this answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638332/1296209

Comment: Sometime I use window.dispatchEvent to trigger event, but it didn't work.But jquery's trigger still work. So nice with jquery.

Comment: this is what I initially tried- it didn't work, but `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));` did

Answer (score 73):

Combining pomber's and avetisk's answers to cover all browsers and not causing warnings:

```
if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
  // modern browsers
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
} else {
  // for IE and other old browsers
  // causes deprecation warning on modern browsers
  var evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
  evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
  window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it across browsers without using jQuery.

Comment: no idea why this isn't the top answer......this is better than the "either or" answers that are accepted....

Answer (score 54):

A pure JS that also works on IE (from [@Manfred comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript#comment49783195_18693617))

```
var evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Or for angular:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var evt = $window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, $window, 0); 
    $window.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation for [UIEvent.initUIEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/initUIEvent) says `Do not use this method anymore as it is deprecated.` The [createEvent docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent#Notes) say "Many methods used with createEvent, such as initCustomEvent, are deprecated. Use [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead." [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent) looks promising for UI events.

Comment: True, but IE11 doesn't support the `new Event()` method. I think as a hack against older browsers you could do something like `if (Event.prototype.initEvent) { /* deprecated method */ } else { /* current method */ }`. Where the current method is the [avetisk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18693617/264628).

Comment: @pomber Thanks for the solution, Actually I was trying to trigger custom event for window resize to resize my chart... your solution save my day

Answer (score 15):

I wasn't actually able to get this to work with any of the above solutions. Once I bound the event with jQuery then it worked fine as below:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    resizeElements();
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Works in Chrome today.

Answer (score 9):

just

```
$(window).resize();
```

is what I use... unless I misunderstand what you're asking for.

Comment: And even if you have jQuery, it only triggers events that were bound with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work for all browsers:

```
var event;
if (typeof (Event) === 'function') {
    event = new Event('resize');
} else { /*IE*/
    event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('resize', true, true);
}
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Works great in Chrome and FF, but didn't work in IE11

Comment: @Collins - thanks for the update, thought I had verified this on IE11...I'll try to take some time later to update this, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Response with RxJS

Say Like something in Angular

```
size$: Observable<number> = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
            debounceTime(250),
            throttleTime(300),
            mergeMap(() => of(document.body.clientHeight)),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            startWith(document.body.clientHeight),
          );
```

If manual subscription desired (Or Not Angular)

```
this.size$.subscribe((g) => {
      console.log('clientHeight', g);
    })
```

Since my intial *startWith* Value might be incorrect (dispatch for correction)

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

In say Angular (I could..)

```
<div class="iframe-container"  [style.height.px]="size$ | async" >..
```

Answer (score -2):

`window.resizeBy()` will trigger window's onresize event. This works in both [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.resizeBy) or [VBScript](http://books.google.com/books?id=LPoCiSSiKXQC&lpg=PA245&ots=-OcsrNP_g6&dq=vbscript%20%22resizeBy%22&pg=PA245#v=onepage&q=vbscript%20%22resizeBy%22&f=false).

`window.resizeBy(xDelta, yDelta)` called like `window.resizeBy(-200, -200)` to shrink page 200px by 200px.

Comment: Why is this marked down? Is it incorrect? Is it browser dependent?

Comment: This doesn't work in **any** browser: Chrome, Firefox, IE, Firefox tested.

Comment: Firefox 7+, and probably other modern browsers, no longer allow calling this method in most cases. In addition, it's not desirable to actually have resize the window in order to trigger the event.

Comment: Both resizeBy() and resizeTo() are working fine in latest stable Chrome ver. 76.0