# Notification of browser size change?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get notified when the browser window size changes? This might happen when the user resizes the browser window etc. I need to resize an element in response to size change,

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to trig the window resize event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trig-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate; asker wants to listen for event, not trigger it

Comment: @SimpleCoder of course, you're right. Here's a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Answer (score 3):

Yes: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

but the event fires crazily. Use this instead (second example down):

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/

When resizing the window, the `resize` event will trigger at every interval, instead of triggering only when the `resize` event is finished. Use debouncing to ensure that it doesn't fire at every interval.