# How can i resolve same bug with jQuery scripts to center a DIV with percentage?

Tags: jquery, image, html, centering

This is my code

```
<style>

.className{
width:55%;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
}

body{
text-align:center;
}

</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).resize(function(){

$('.className').css({
position:'absolute',
left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
});

});
// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();

});

</script>
```

When I open my page i see my DIV not centred, but when i reduce and i reopen in full mod the window of my browser, the DIV is perfectly centred, plz help me I'm going crazy
I try to change

This

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).resize(function(){

$('.className').css({
position:'absolute',
left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
});

});
// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();

});

</script>
```

With this (TXH TO Elhussein Hashem)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     resizeFunction();

    window.onresize = function() {
        resizeFunction();
    };

     resizeFunction();

});

function resizeFunction(){
    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(document).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(document).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });
}
</script>
```

But the result is not change :(

I have noticed that even when I refresh the page, all back centered as when I reduce and reopen the browser window

This is the DIV

```
<div class="className">
<div><img style="width:100%" src="http://i39.tinypic.com/5f506d.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

P L Z 
H E L P
M E

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix my jQuery centering DIV percentage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617553/how-can-i-fix-my-jquery-centering-div-percentage)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if we could see the page, but you could try using window.load.  I'm guessing, as your class has an image, the ready is getting called before the .className has a width (it knows it has an image, but doesn't know the size of the image).

```
<script>
//window.load waits for graphics to finish loading before running
$(window).load(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('.className').css({
      position:'absolute',
      left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
      top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });
  });
  // To initially run the function:
  $(window).resize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the same too +1

Comment: @dave thx 1000, work but there is another small problem, now when i open the website for some second 1-2 i see the div bugged like the old code but after 1 2 sec the div is self-centering in the middle of the page, WHY?