# Google Maps API showing blank map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm sure this is a basic problem but I've hit my head against the wall too many times now, so hopefully someone will take pity on me!

I have the following example but all it does is show a grayed out box, no map at all. Can anyone tell me why?

I've checked that I'm actually returning a result and it seems to be working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
        </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      var geocoder;
      var map;

      function initialize() 
      {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();        
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "England"}, function(results, status) 
        {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
          {
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            // Let's draw the map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

          } 
          else 
          {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }

    initialize();
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="">
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`results[0].geometry.location` is already a latLng object so you can just say:

```
center: results[0].geometry.location
```

Find the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/87z9K/

Comment: Nice catch, hope you don't mind. Added the fiddle in your answer for the OP to verify .

Comment: @putvande That works! Just for my reference, where does it make the latLng object?

Answer (score 9):

Try resizing the browser window, give a shake to browser/drag it from browser tab with the cursor and you will see the map appearing.

From some strange reason in MVC partial view google map comes as blank, your map is working it just need to be resized.

Shaking a browser window with cursor sounds funny, but it works and I am not sure how to best describe it.

Thanks,
Anurag

=======================================================================

my final working code is below:

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        (function () {
            var options = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.633333, 37.233334),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            // init map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);


            var arrLocation = [];
            $("#markerDiv").find("div").each(function () {
                var Lat = $(this).find("input[id='Latitude']").val();
                var Lon = $(this).find("input[id='Longitude']").val();
                var Id = $(this).find("input[id='Id']").val();
                var AssessmentDet = $(this).find("input[id='AssessmentDateTime']").val();
                var LocAcc = $(this).find("input[id='LocationAccuracy']").val();
                var assessorName = $(this).find("input[id='AssessorName']").val();
                var partnerName = $(this).find("input[id='PartnerName']").val();
                arrLocation.push({
                    Id: Id,
                    Latitude: Lat,
                    Longitude: Lon,
                    AssessmentDate: AssessmentDet,
                    LocationAccuracy: LocAcc,
                    AssessorDetail: assessorName,
                    PartnerName: partnerName
                    });
            });

            var allMarkers = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < arrLocation.length; i++) {

                //final position for marker, could be updated if another marker already exists in same position
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrLocation[i].Latitude, arrLocation[i].Longitude);
                var finalLatLng = latlng;
                var comparelatlng = "(" + arrLocation[i].Latitude + "," + arrLocation[i].Longitude + ")";
                var copyMarker = arrLocation[i];

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arrLocation[i].Latitude, arrLocation[i].Longitude),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Equine # ' + arrLocation[i].Id,
                    icon:"abc.png"
                });


                var markerInfo = "Reference # : <b>" + arrLocation[i].Id + "</b><br/>";
                markerInfo = markerInfo + "Assessor : <b>" + arrLocation[i].AssessorDetail + "</b><br/>";
                markerInfo = markerInfo + "Date :  <b>" + arrLocation[i].AssessmentDate + "</b><br/>";
                markerInfo = markerInfo + "Partner :  <b>" + arrLocation[i].PartnerName + "</b>";(function (marker, i) {

  bindInfoWindow(marker, map, new google.maps.InfoWindow(), markerInfo);
                })(marker, i);
            }
        })();
    });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }


</script>
```

`

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and yes, resizing the browser window does kick it into finishing loading. No clue why or what to do about it.

Comment: LOL, It works but what is the main reason behind this @Anurag

Comment: I'm currently fighting against this behaviour and have tried various things like triggering a resize. My issue I think is due to how the DOM object is not loaded correctly in angular ui router

Comment: I am facing the same issue as well! Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @Anand I got it working by creating a <DIV id="map"> and then through ajax replaced the div content with _partial view text, also make sure in your partial view you have specified center point and zoom level for map as below, 
`code`

var options = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.633333, 37.233334),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            // init map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

`code`

Comment: @Anurag, resizing the WHOLE window works, but I can't see what your code has to do with resizing.  For me,  jQuery trigger did not work. This worked: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`. Although the [best method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846782/673991) probably includes alternatives for IE, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the worng "google.maps.LatLng" provided.
provide for a test the coords and it will work.
replace the line

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location),
```

with

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

get England coords

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't exactly your issue, but closely related.

I found that I had to set the mapOptions with a valid `centre`, like so:

```
new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
});
```

If I didn't enter map options, or if I did and it didn't have a valid `center` set, I'd get a blank map that didn't load tiles.

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur if the height/width of the map is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set map's MapTypeId and it helped as Anurag proposed:

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
```

Answer (score -4):

I can see a general javascript issue with your code.

Your script might trying to embed the map in the page before the HTML is loaded.

Call the function like this (there are other ways).

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

Comment: That's not the actual problem, See the answers below. Those highlight the problem that's there with the code.

Comment: @Padrig, I've actually tried this but when I do the map box doesn't even load.