# jQuery + iframe, onresize

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a page on my site that uses jQuery to add items to a table without reloading the page. It works perfectly but now I need to display it in another page using an iframe.

I can get it to display but the issue I'm running into is that of scrollbars in the iframe which I'd really like to avoid. Is there a way I can dynamically resize the iframe height when jQuery increases the height of the table?

What I've tried so far

- onresize() method in the iframe as mentioned here and I added an alert to display when the onresize function is triggered but it never does. [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)
- Tried forcing a resize in the original page but the alert still doesn't show up in the page with the iframe. 
  [How to trigger the window resize event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript)

No matter what I try, I just can't seem to get this to work. I'm new to jQuery and I'm pretty much out of ideas now.

Help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: another page or another domain?

Comment: Another page. Both pages are on the same domain and have to remain separate pages because CSS seems to clash and it's not easy to change it because I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: i once solved this with easyXdm, an easy jquery plugin for communication between iframe and consumer page

Comment: http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/