# Window resize trigger event is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I want to call the resize event using code.

I am using following code .It is working fine in otherbrowsers but not in the IE11.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
            $(window).trigger('resize');

        } else {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

        }
```

Please advice me, am I missing anything?

Comment: Just use `$(window).trigger('resize')` it will work in IE 11 also

Comment: @Satpal nope,It is not working :(

Comment: @rightPath Provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue in question itself. And so post code binding event you are trying to trigger or better explain what you are looking for, don't just say `it is not working`...

Answer (score 31):

Even **Internet explorer 11** does not support resize event. Therefore, I have resolved this by using following solution.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
     var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
     evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
     window.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else {
       window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Shivek - this was the only answer that worked for me after trying many other possible solutions.  The key was to use UIEvents and not HTMLEvents

Comment: My code works fine for everything except IE so is the else {} needed? Thanks,

Comment: This is great, this is the only solution that does not result in many errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var resizeEvent = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
resizeEvent .initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from the other post [How to trigger the window resize event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript/43846782#43846782) that I came across works well.

Snippet of the same:

```js
if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
    // modern browsers
     window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
} else {
    // for IE and other old browsers
    // causes deprecation warning on modern browsers
    var evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```