# nvd3 chart starts out squished in browser

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have searched the internet for a solution to this problem but have yet to come across one yet.  I was hoping someone here has had experience with this and can help point me in the right direction.

I have a line chart created with Angular-nvd3 and I am using Bootstrap for responsiveness.  Basically I have two charts per row.  The problem I am running into is that when I first load the page, the charts are squished into a small width.  I am not setting the width on the charts so that it can inherit 100% width and fill the container.  As soon as I do anything with the browser, such as open the console or resize the browser, the charts scale to their correct width.  I was wondering if there was any way to force a resize.  I had a similar issue before when using c3d3 but using chart.resize() solved the issue.  I do not know if nvd3 has a similar method as I do not have as much experience with nvd3.  I was wondering if there was a similar method I could use or if there was a pure way with d3 to do this.

Here are some before and after pics to help visualize the issue:

Before:  [image]

After opening the console or resizing the browser in any way, it scales correctly:  [image]

EDIT:  I should add that setting a fixed width circumvents the issue but then the inherent responsiveness goes away (new problems arise where graphs overlap at smaller browser sizes)

EDIT:  Added Some code snippets that I hope can help.  I am using rows and columns the Bootstrap way.  I am also declaring the chart options in the JS

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <nvd3 id="inlet" options="inletOptions" data="inletData"></nvd3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <nvd3 id="outlet" options="outletOptions" data="outletData"></nvd3>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.inletOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: 300,
        margin : {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 40,
            left: 55
        },
        x: function(d) { return d.x; },
        y: function(d) { return d.y; }
    }
};
```

Comment: You could just trigger a [window resize event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18693617/16363).  I believe `nvd3` is just listening for that event.

Comment: Still running into the same issue.  I tried triggering the resize event in both the chart options callback and function where I am loading the page.  This actually causes the chart to shrink again every time I load the page as opposed to before when it would fix after first browser re-size, even if I navigated back to the page.

Comment: Can you set up a minimal code sample which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Please see updated question with code snippets

Comment: **minimal code sample which demonstrates your problem** -- do those 8 lines of HTML and 14 lines of JS reproduce your problem? I even went way above and beyond [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/90izqsa7kBq4Qh2n2gpD?p=preview) but I can't reproduce what you are seeing...

Comment: Sorry for the minimal amount of code.  There wasn't much I could add that could help demonstrate the problem.  After looking at your Fiddle I decided to a bit more digging and found [this post](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/259) on github with a link to [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ncT72d?p=preview) that demonstrates the problem.   your initial proposal works great.  the solution was to force the window resize after a minimal timeout on page load.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those running into a similar issue, please see the following posts:

https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/259

http://plnkr.co/edit/ncT72d?p=preview

```
$scope.triggerResizeEvent = function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

Comment: Also noticed, that the core problem stems from using ng-cloak

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is running into this problem, for me it was actually a very simple solution **without** a resize event.

This is my chart.

```
<div id="chart" class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I have no data to show, I simply hide the div using JavaScript:

```
function ShowChart(show) {
  $('#chart').css("display", (show ? "block" : "none"));
}
```

But it was squished when I passed "true" to the function.

My solution was that I had to first show the div, then use .update() for the graph.

So, for me, this did **not** work:

```
d3.select("#chart svg").datum(chart_data); 
chart.update();
ShowChart(true);
```

And this **did**:

```
ShowChart(true);
d3.select("#chart svg").datum(chart_data); 
chart.update()
```