# How to adjust column of datatables 1.10 on javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a navigation bar in my wesite with a anchor element as toggle for side navigation bar.

```
<a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button" onclick="toggle_click()">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 </a>
```

when i click the toggle the side navigation will hide/display.

there are dataTable in the content. those datatable columns are not auto resizing themselves when this toggle event is triggered.but the columns gets auto resized on other events like (zoom,window size change, any event on the datable like (search, changing the number of entries to display)).

image of taggle sidebar
[image]

image of closed side bar
[image]

so i want to know how to make this happen when the toggle is triggered.

i tried

```
function toggle_click() {
       var mtable = $('#open_ticket_table').DataTable();
       mtable.responsive.recalc();
}

function toggle_click() {
       var mtable = $('#open_ticket_table').DataTable();
       mtable.columns.adjust();
}
```

all the possible thigs in the internet

Comment: Just do `$(window).trigger('resize')`

Comment: it is not working @skobaljic i debugged the code. It is executing the code but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @skobaljic we can trigger a javascript resize event.
but his code dint work, i dont know why.

after some googling i got this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18693617/5695035) on triggering resize event by using the below code.

```
 window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

unfortunately i dint get any datatables plugin solution for this problem.