# Make google chart responsive

Tags: javascript, charts

Im  using google charts in a project but im having a hard time to make them responsive.

Iǘe seen other examples on responsive charts but I cant seem to get it to work in my case.
All my charts gets rendered and after that their sizes do not change.

If someone can make this chart responsive id appreciate it. Thank you:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Revenue');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Average Revenue');
    data.addRows([
      ['2004', 1000, 630],
      ['2005', 1170, 630],
      ['2006', 660, 630],
      ['2007', 1030, 630]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Revenue by Year',
      seriesType: "bars",
      series: {1: {type: "line"}},  
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',
              titleTextStyle:{color: 'red'}},
        colors:['red','black']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Fiddle for the chart:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtwy0cfv/)

If it could take up a percentage width of a parent it would be great

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution was already given online elsewhere.

You need to call your drawChart() function whenever the window is resized to get the desired behaviour.  The website [flopreynat.com](https://flopreynat.com/blog/2015-09-08-make-google-charts-responsive) exactly describes this problem and solution ([codepen](https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA)).  It describes how this can be done using JQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart();
});
```

Using just Javascript, [this answer on Stack Exchange by Sohnee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript) describes how to trigger functions upon a resize event:

```
window.onresize = doALoadOfStuff;

function doALoadOfStuff() {
    //do a load of stuff
}
```

All credit to both authors of the links above.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I am using a similar approach now. I re-render the chart on window resize. But I hope to be able to achieve responsiveness without re-rendering. Here is an example that only seems to use css but i cant seem to recreate it on my own chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/toddlevy/pyAz5/

Comment: That example appears to use the throttledresize event to redraw it, not just CSS.

Comment: Oh! I did not realize that...thank you Paul for enlightening me. I guess using js is the only way then...Considering that your answer actually makes the charts responsive, iĺl mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Add width_units to your option block:

```js
var options = {
    width: 80,
    width_units: '%'
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to explain how adding this width option would make the chart responsive.

Comment: I can't believe this had a negative vote! It's so simple answer and it works!

Comment: This works on mobile, but the chart stays small on a wider screen. Not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class chart, and used the window resize event like the accepted answer.

css:

```
.chart {
          width: 100%; 
          min-height: 500px;
        }
```

js:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
          drawChart();
        });
```

html:

```
<div id="barchart" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or simply use:

```js
var options = {
  responsive: true,
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).