# jquery resize function trigger does not work multiple time

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have bootstrap carousel in which a slick slider call when I click second tab its work fine but when click on third tab  window.resize function not working,vice versa

```
 jQuery(document).on('click', ".wt-prcNew2-do, .wt-prcNew2-linode, .wt-prcNew2-vl, .wt-prcNew2-amz", function() {
        jQuery(window).trigger("resize");
    });
```

Comment: What's in your resize function? We don't see anything..

Comment: I just want when user   click on .wt-prcNew2-do so resize event trigger

Comment: So, what's in the resize event?

Comment: resize is  jQuery  function

Comment: Just having resize won't do anything. You must have definition for resize.

Comment: @noni are you trying to simulate resizing the browser?

Comment: @TylerFowle I resize because when tab change it contain 0 width so the inner html make slide with 0 width so i want before click on it resize and get width of window its work 1st time but not more than 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger the window resize event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript)