# How can I force a matching window.matchMedia to execute on page load?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I noticed a difference between css media query definition and the javascript window.matchMedia media query definition:

The css rules are apllied initially to a loaded page.

The rules defined in javascript are not executed after the page load, but only after a new condition is entered.

An example:

I have two different pages with equivalent media query definitions, the first one defined in css and the second one defined in javascript:

the css version (defined in a style element):

```
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px) { body {background-color: red; } }
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px) { body {background-color: blue; } }
```

the javascript version (defined either globally or in a function called after body onload):

```
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)")
.addListener(function(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    document.body.style.background = "red";
  }
});

window.matchMedia("(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px)")
.addListener(function(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
  }
});
```

When I load a page and the window is 700 px wide

- the css version page is blue
- the javascript version is white and changes its state only after a new condition is met, i.e. the window is sized below 601 px.

How can I force a matching window.matchMedia to execute on page load?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript

Comment: I know window.onresize and body onload and I am aware that I could use those to solve my problem. But I assumed that this is not necessary. I believed window.matchMedia behaves the same as the css solution. I thought registering the queries once with callback functions would and should be enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fire a `matchMedia` on load, you could do like this instead (with a somewhat *cleaner* code base).

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
      
        // medias (as an array to make it a little easier to manage)
        var mqls = [
          window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)"),
          window.matchMedia("(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)"),
          window.matchMedia("(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px)"),
          window.matchMedia("(min-width: 801px)")
        ]
        
        // event listeners
        for (var i=0; i<mqls.length; i++){
          mqls[i].addListener(mqh)
        }
        
        // matches methods
        function mqh(){
          if (mqls[0].matches) {
            console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 400px)");
            document.body.style.background = "green";
          } else if (mqls[1].matches) {
            console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 600px)");
            document.body.style.background = "red";
          } else if (mqls[2].matches) {
            console.log("CALLBACK (max-width: 800px)");
            document.body.style.background = "blue";
          } else if (mqls[3].matches) {
            console.log("CALLBACK (min-width: 801px)");        
            document.body.style.background = "gray";
          }
          console.log("window.innerWidth: " + window.innerWidth);
        }

        // call once on load
        mqh();
      });
      
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

*Org. src: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/matchmediamultiple.shtml*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like the same approach in my answer.

Comment: @NathanPerigreth The main difference is mine doesn't need the `resize` event

Comment: You're right. But that means you have to 1) explicitly call the match function for the page load and you have to 2) bind the match function as a callback function in case of a page resize. Is that the better solution?

Comment: @NathanPerigreth If you post the code for your own suggestion, I'll either stick to mine, or delete it and upvote yours :)

Comment: From your experience, which solution would you prefer? I find both a bit clumsy compared to the css solution (which of course cannot be used when javascript functionality is needed).

Comment: Then I'd go with the built-in callback I showed, since that one is most likely much more efficient than copy its behavior using `resize`

Comment: @NathanPerigreth Updated with a somewhat smoother setup :)

Answer (score 3):

A callback function bound to window.matchMedia is not called on page load.

A solution to the problem would be:

- to define a function in which the media queries are explicitly checked via `if(window.matchMedia("...").matches){`
- to call that function on page load via `<body onload`
- to call that function on resize via `window.onresize`

Comment: Since this is as well a viable option, plus 1

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem today, and I've used the following solution inspired by [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9665818/nathan-perigreth):

```js
const gate = 800

function listener(
  matches,
) {
  document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML = matches ? 'wider' : 'narrower'
}

window.onload=() => {
  const match = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${gate}px)`)
  match.addListener(e => listener(e.matches))
  listener(match.matches)
}
```

```html
<h1>
  This window is 
  <span id='tag'></span>
  than 800px
</h1>
```

The core concept is to run your listener function once with [MediaQueryList.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/matches) passed as a parameter.

And if someone is trying to achieve this with a framework, do remember to register and trigger the listener during the component mount event.

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: @ZachSaucier -- If you also explain why it should be the top answer, users would have something more substantial to consider an upvote. Also do note, the OP has several media queries to set up, which I can't see how that can be simpler (and better) than I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me

```
function media(args, callback) {
let mqList = window.matchMedia(args);
function handle(mediaEvent) {
    if (mediaEvent.matches) {
        callback(mediaEvent)
    } else {
        callback(mediaEvent)
    }
}
mqList.addEventListener('change', handle);
handle(mqList) // Initial check
}
```

Usage

```
media('(max-width: 920px)', (e) => {
    console.log(e.matches)//false/true
})
```

From https://css-tricks.com/working-with-javascript-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

In `React` + `TS` you would want something like the following. Lodash's `throttle` is optional.

```js
  const [isSmallScreen, setIsSmallScreen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const throttleUpdate = throttle((ev: MediaQueryListEvent) => setIsSmallScreen(ev.matches), 150);
    // 768 = md, https://ant.design/components/layout#breakpoint-width
    const matchMedia = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');
    setIsSmallScreen(matchMedia.matches);

    matchMedia.addEventListener('change', throttleUpdate);
    return () => matchMedia.removeEventListener('change', throttleUpdate);
  }, []);
  
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If something is triggered by an event, there gotta be a way to fire that event manually.

```
const screenLg = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px)')

screenLg.addEventListener('change', ({ matches }) => {
  // your usual logic, without special cases for page load
})

// Fire the 'change' event, which you're subscribed on above, manually
screenLg.dispatchEvent(new MediaQueryListEvent('change', screenLg))
```