# How can I fire the following listener onload using the following matchMedia

Tags: viewport, onload, matchmedia

I have the below code. How can it be triggered automatically when the screen load by defaults or it is refreshed?

```js
function screenSize(){
  const mobile = window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 573px)');
  const tablet = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 572px) and (max-width: 990px)');
  const desktop = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 990px)');

  mobile.addListener(function(evt){
    if(evt.matches) {
      alert("Mobile-view")
    }
  });

  tablet.addListener(function(evt){
    if(evt.matches) {
      alert("Tablet-view")
    }
  })

  desktop.addListener(function(evt){
    if(evt.matches) {
      alert("desktop-view")
    }
  });
}

screenSize()
```

It is only triggered when the viewport is resized. How can I make it fire when the viewport is loaded or refreshed?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59623249/5774952) for how to test media queries on load in JS. But that won't fix all your problems: you have several typos.  `screenSiz -> screenSize`, `checkTablet -> tablet`, `checkDesktop -> desktop` (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks Zac, typo error corrected. 
However, I can’t seamz to be able to have my head rap around those solution that are posted in that link. Considering the fact that I already have a function that is already wrapped around some viewport listeners

Comment: Yeah so the core problem is that you really need to check if the query matches on load, not wait for a listener to fire. I'll add an answer with some example code, though there are several ways to do it (including ones in the answers to the question I linked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above, this is a solution to this specific problem. The answer I linked in the comments has some other possible solutions. The core problem is that queries need to be checked for `.matches` (bool) on window or document load, not just have listeners added to them.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  // set up your queries just as strings
  const mobile = 'screen and (max-width: 573px)'
  const tablet = 'screen and (min-width: 572px) and (max-width: 990px)'
  const desktop = 'screen and (min-width: 990px)'

  // loop over those as an obj so you have convenient key names
  Object.entries({ mobile, tablet, desktop })
    .forEach(([key, val]) => {
      // create a query object
      const query = window.matchMedia(val)
      // check if the query currently matches and alert if so
      if (query.matches) {
        alert(`${key}-view`)
      }

      // add the listener for resize events
      query.addListener((e) => {
        if (e.matches) {
          alert(`${key}-view`)
        }
      })
    })
}
```

And to use different functions for each breakpoint, you could do it like this:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const mobileQuery = 'screen and (max-width: 573px)'
  const tabletQuery = 'screen and (min-width: 572px) and (max-width: 990px)'
  const desktopQuery = 'screen and (min-width: 990px)'

  const mobileListener = (e) => { console.log('on mobile') }
  const tabletListener = (e) => { console.log('on tablet') }
  const desktopListener = (e) => { console.log('on desktop') }

  const breakpoints = {
    // this object has your media query strings as keys and
    // functions to run on those breakpoints as values
    [mobileQuery]: mobileListener,
    [tabletQuery]: tabletListener,
    [desktopQuery]: desktopListener
  }

  Object.entries(breakpoints)
    .forEach(([query, fn]) => {
      const q = window.matchMedia(query)
      q.addListener(fn)
      if (q.matches) fn()
    })
}
```

Comment: one more thing. now that I have been able to fire the onload by default with your solution. how can I run a function for each viewport? previously this is what I did.

Comment: `function screenSize(){
const mobile = window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 573px)');
const tablet = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 572px) and (max-width: 990px)');
const desktop = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 990px)');

mobile.addListener(function(evt){
    if(evt.matches) {
      mobi ()
    }
  });

tablet.addListener(function(evt){
    if(evt.matches) {
      tab ()
    }
  })

desktop.addListener(function(evt){
    if(evt.matches) {
      desk ()
    }
  });
}
screenSize()`

Comment: and these are the functions that I want to run for each viewport, 
`() mobi => {}`,
`() tab => {}`,
`() desk => {}`

so how can I incorporate each of these functions with the appropriate viewports.

Many thanks for your earlier code.

Comment: @Kiki-ko Check out what I just added to my answer — there are several ways you could do this but the core idea is to map your breakpoints to your listeners, so using the same concept as the initial version, I just changed the object being iterated over to include custom listeners per breakpoint

Comment: perfect. That solves it.  putting my function in each listener
`const mobileListener = (e) => { mobi () }`
  `const tabletListener = (e) => { tab () }`,
  `const desktopListener = (e) => { desk () ) `

 was triggered according to the viewports.

Many thanks, Problem solved