# Angular jasmine test not able to trigger Observable created with fromEvent rxjs operator

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, angular-test

I have a simple case. The standard `AppComponent` of an Angular app contains a `ChildComponent` which is defined in its own module `ChildModule`.

The template of `ChildComponent` is very simple

```
<div class="child" (click)="testClick($event)"></div>
```

`ChildComponent` has an even simpler `testClick(event)` method that just logs a message on the console.

```
testClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Now I want to build a test on `AppComponent` simulating a click on `ChildComponent`.

This is the code of the test

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let app: AppComponent;
  let child: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ChildModule ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    child = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.child'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it(`should create the child'`, async(() => {
    expect(child).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`clicks on the child and the relative Observable emits`, async(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      child.triggerEventHandler('click', 'clicked');
    }, 100);

  }));

});
```

The tests work and in particular the second test prints the `clicked` message on the console, as expected.

Now I complicate a bit `ChildComponent`. I want to create an Observable on the `click` event using the `fromEvent` operator and `ViewChild`.

So the code becomes

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('child') private childElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const testClick$ = fromEvent(this.childElement.nativeElement, 'click');
    testClick$.subscribe(d => console.log('test click in child', d));
  }
}
```

I launch the development server with `ng serve` and I see 2 messages printed on the console, one by the `testClick` method and one by the subscription of the `testClick$` Observable.

If I run now the same tests as before, I expect to see also the same two messages printed on the console. On the contrary I see only the message printed by the `testClick` method. The message of the subscription, i.e. `'test click in child'`, does not appear, which means that the Observable `testClick$` does not emit when `child.triggerEventHandler('click', 'clicked');` is executed.

How can I make Observables created with `fromEvent` work in **jasmine** tests? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you mock the `fromEvent` method ? cuz testing whether fromEvent works or not should not be your unit test's responsibility. You should `assume fromEvent will always work` cuz it is coming from an external library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually I found a way to fire events that can be used within the `fromEvent` function of RxJs.

The solution has been inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript).

The idea is that in order to be able to create an event stream from a DOM event you have to use the method `dispatchEvent` on the native element wrapped by the DebugElement.

So, rather than doing

```
child.triggerEventHandler('click', 'clicked');
```

you have to use something like

```
child.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {...});
```