# Unit test for fromEvent in service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-runner

I've a service that detects if a CTRL/CMD key is pressed. It is used in various components to check (among other things) if links should open in a new tab or not.

**Service:**

```
keyDownListenerCTRL = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(window, 'keydown').pipe(
tap((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (
    event.metaKey ||
    event.ctrlKey ||
    event.key === 'Meta' ||
    event.key === 'Ctrl'
  ) {
    this.isControlButtonHeld = true;
  }
})
);

constructor() {
    this.keyDownListenerCTRL.subscribe();
}
```

I don't know how to test this. There is no HTML element that I could simulate a click on, so using a dispatchEvent (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463410/angular-jasmine-test-not-able-to-trigger-observable-created-with-fromevent-rxjs)) does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same thing as the answer you linked to, but on the window object.

```
const evt = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {   
  key: 'Control',
  code: 'ControlLeft',
  ctrlKey: true
});
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

A few things...

- You might be better off using **renderer.listen** to attach to the event.  This way you don't have to reference an non-injected global object like window, and the technique above will still work.
- If you can, consider using **HostListener** instead of **fromEvent** as now testing is a simple as calling a method.

```
// injecting document and using renderer.
constructor (private renderer: Renderer2) { 
  this.renderer.listen('window', 'keydown', event => { /* do stuff */ });
}

// Using HostListner to listen to control and escape
@HostListener('window:keydown.control')
@HostListener('window:keydown.escape')
onKeyDown(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
  this.isControlButtonHeld = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the smart advice, I'm really appreciating it. I don't believe it's possible to use a HostListener in a service, but renderer is a good idea.