# react-data-grid x-axis scroll issue

Tags: css, reactjs, react-data-grid

react data grid x-axis scroll not working on browser(crome), my current(70.0.3538.77) version (crome) but working on previous version(69.***). But working fine
with other browser.
My React Version is "react": "16.4.1",
React-data-grid version is "react-data-grid": "4.0.8","react-data-grid-addons": "4.0.8"

[image: Expected Result]

[image: Getting No Scroll Option]

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?
I'm having the same issue

Comment: Upgrad your version now i'm using "react-data-grid": "5.0.3",
    "react-data-grid-addons": "^5.0.3",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had to implement a workaround that fakes a `resize` event. That made [react-data-grid](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/)
 to re-render and show the scrollbars again:

```
componentDidMount () {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        const event = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents');

        event.initUIEvent( 'resize', true, false, window, 0);

        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
}
```

(see also: [How to trigger the window resize event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript/18693617))