# How to redraw all subtable at once / Nested Tables

Tags: javascript, html, nested, tabulator

I have a tabulator with subtable on each lane (Nested Tables example). I wanted to redraw all the subtable when i detect a change in screen resolution. But I'm blocked because "subtable.redraw();" don't work.
Did someone have an idea ?
I can change properties of the subtable div but without redraw(), i can't resize my column.

Comment: You could [trigger a resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript), that would reflow and redraw everything in your page.

Comment: I cant do that because my main table need 30s to load my data. I just want to redraw my mini subtable without modify the main table.

Comment: Your language might be imprecise. There's a clear difference between "reload" and "reflow/redraw". The latter can be done without reloading the data and rebuilding the DOM.