# Refreshing page automatically when viewport size change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using responsive and adaptive media queries for my website to accommodate smartphones...Now the problem is that my max-width mobile query ends at 480px, which is most phones rotated display width (when the phone is on its side...). Now some phones, like the HTC desire have a max screen width of 533px, now when the user first loads the page on vertical position (320px screen width) and he/she rotates rotates the screen to 533px width, it goes past my design specifications and it looks kinda crappy...(since the layout was meant for 480px max...)

Now the only way to solve that is to refresh the page once the viewport dimensions change. How do I force a refresh?

Thank you

Comment: Does this help? http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize_mobile.html

Comment: I would be a pretty upset user if a page had to refresh every time I rotated my phone. That's the kind of thing that will make me close your website and never come back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if device rotate window resized.

```
window.onresize = function(event)
{
document.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you ILker...appreciate. Is there a way to force the screen to rotate (if the device is capable) on a mobile phone?

Comment: for some reason on my HTC desire android 2.3.3 native browser that code makes my page refresh continuously...

Comment: mobile browser has a rotate event but i am not use this. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript maybe helpful your problem.

Comment: solution for continuous refresh on scroll is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455463/1449147