# Refresh page on resize with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to force the browser to refresh the page when the user resizes it. I have following code:

```
function refresh() { location.reload(); }

<body onResize="refresh()">
```

but it does not work. Does anyone of you has a solution?
Thanks

Comment: onresize, not onResize.

Comment: thats given by dreamweaver, i dont think its wrong! but i also tested "onresize" before posting this!

Comment: HTML attributes are case-insensitive. But in JavaScript those properties are lowercased.

Comment: technically uppercase html attributes are "invalid" according to visual studio (or maybe it's resharper). They aren't, but it does look  pretty ugly when they're capitalized.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Do it with javascript/jquery:

just javascript:

```
window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }
```

with jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});
```

or

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){location.reload();});
```

Comment: Vanilla JS is `onresize` btw, as also previously commented by JohnFx.

Comment: worked, but not on firefox! do you have a clou why?

Comment: @TedMosby nope, that's weird. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. It's possible that you have another javascript error somewhere on the page that comes up in firefox, and it's causing this javascript not to run. Hit f12 and check the console window for errors.

Comment: Fair enough. Been a while since I used the native javascript ones.

Comment: No problem. I believe it is a fair mistake as you use solely the event name for `addEventListener` / `jQuery` but have to prefix it with `on` when using the property.

Comment: Hello, this is an old post but thought to write this anyhow, the first and last version will make IE9 constantly refresh, the middle one though will work as expected :)

Comment: `window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }` doesn't do anything as far as I can see.

Comment: Remember that safari on mobile devices slightly changes the resolution when the user starts scrolling. This makes a page unusable because it hangs in an reload loop every time the scrolling event starts. To avoid this, set a `threshold` for resolution changes (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66530647/2056125 ).

Comment: I am facing an issue though, when I am using this on mobile and someone scrolls down then the window reloads as well for some reason.

Answer (score 30):

The following code seems to work with all browsers,

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
  if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
  window.RT = setTimeout(function()
  {
    this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
  }, 100);
});
```

Hope it helps everyone. I found this information here: http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-refresh-page-browser-resize/

Comment: What does window.RT means this context ?

Comment: On the window.RT question. I not exactly sure. I found the solution at the link I provided and it worked so I didn't ask many questions. ;) I simply shared this for others to use. I'd suggest if you have specific code questions you reference the link and ask the person who posted it. It may have something to do with Windows RT, but like I said I'm not sure. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: It appears that this code is creating a property called `RT` on the `window` object. It is using that to check whether it needs to clear the timeout before it creates a new one. Many would've simply let it (silently) error the first time through but this is probably better.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain to me what this code is doing? This is the **only** variant that has worked for me so far, but I would have been incapable of coming with it myself as I do not understand it.

Comment: setTimeout returns an ID for the timer created. This code variation saves that ID in a property, so if the user is resizing window before 1st timer had chance to run, subsequent run of the same event aborts existing timer (clearTimeout) - before creating a new one.  When the user is finished resizing, event will stop triggering and reload finally called. As to what RT means, maybe reload timer? You can use whatever you like as property name, as long as it is not reserved or used somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        location.reload();
});
```