# JS refresh browser on viewport change only safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I know you can force a reload of all elements on a page using JS. Is there a way to do this only when the browser is Safari?

(screen orientation changes seem to mess up a layout that I've created only for Safari)

[Refresh page on resize with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915653/refresh-page-on-resize-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use :

    var  isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/);
         if (isSafari){
      //run your page refresh code           
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! How would I specify Safari  any version  5. anything or less?