# Page reload/print conflict

Tags: javascript

On a webpage, I have a simple script to refresh the page when the browser resizes to force an embedded Tableau file to resize correctly:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {"use strict"; window.location.reload();})
```

I'm running into a problem using this script when the user tries to print the page using the browser's print button - the page reloads, and cancels the printing. How can I force the reload/resize event without affecting the print functionality?

Comment: I would imagine there is a way to resize a table that doesn't involve refreshing the page -  can you provide more details on what this 'Tableau file' is?

Comment: reload on refresh, sounds like a bad design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh page on resize with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915653/refresh-page-on-resize-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: A Tableau file (Tableau Server) is an interactive data charting file, like Business Objects or Google Charts. My page, itself, is responsive. It's this file that requires a refresh to initiate a resize to fill any changes to the browser window size.