# How to resize a window using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, resize, window

JQuery has an event called resize using which you can add an event handler when the window is resized e.g.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
// code here
});
```

What I'd need is to resize the window using a JQuery command; would that be possible?

e.g. $(window).resize(-1, -1); // to decrease/increase the width and height of the window

Thanks

Comment: You should check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use this, its a pure javascript no JQuery involved.

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

Comment: thanks. window.resizeBy was what I was after. It's odd it doesn't work with values less than 100 e.g. window.resizeBy(100, 100);

Comment: I think there is some minimum value for height and width which you can set it to a window. If it helped you can you please accept my answer?

Comment: Note that some browsers sensibly won't allow you to resize the main window, potentially full of tabs with other web pages. But you can resize a window you opened as a popup (i.e. via window.open).

Comment: Is it possible to animate this - so that the window appears to expand/shrink rather than just snapping to the new size?

Answer (score -3):

sorry looks like that binds an event handler to the "resize" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

see:
http://api.jquery.com/resize/