# Jquery Dynamic Window Resize

Tags: javascript, loops, jquery, window-resize

I am trying to resize the window from a given array of integers. Here is my current incorrect code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

var group = [0, 1, 2];

var global_i = 0;

$.each(group,function(i){

    //some code will execute here

    console.log('#');

    resize_window_width_helper(1000-(i*10));        

    $(window).on('debouncedresize.rs'+i, function() {   

        if(i == global_i){

            //execute another bit of code on resize

            console.log("Hello from " + i);

            console.log('body width = '+$('body').width());

            global_i++;

        }

    });

});

});
```

The return from my console is:

```
#
#
#
Hello from 0
body width = 941 
Hello from 1 
body width = 941 
Hello from 2 
body width = 941
```

The return i was expecting is:

```
#
Hello from 0
body width = 961
#
Hello from 1
body width = 951
#
Hello from 2
body width = 941
```

The contents of the array `group` will vary.

The function `resize_window_width_helper(input)` will simply resize the window width to its argument value.

The event `debouncedresize` is a fix for the Chrome browser firing off any resizes twice (see http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/ and https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize#minimalist-standalone-version). So please treat this event as a simple `$(window).resize(function() {...});`.

I am using the Google Chrome browser.

I strongly suspect the source of all my woes lies in the variable `i` and the method in which it is incremented. I deeply appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is "resize_window_width_helper" resizing the body or is is resizing the window? Please include code for this function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that funtion resizes the window: `function resize_window_width_helper(new_width){
 
 resizeTo(new_width, screen.availHeight);}`

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709408/how-to-resize-a-window-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the link - i've tried that method as well as the timer resize method suggested in the followup link. They sadly do not work.

Comment: Are you assuming the 'body' width changes when the window size is changed?