# How to resize window on click

Tags: jquery

```
$("#show > div").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).html();
    alert (a); // 860
    window.resizeTo(a + "px", 450 + "px");
});
```

The above is the accepted answer from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709408/how-to-resize-a-window-using-jquery) SO post.

But doesn't work. On click - nothing happens !

Comment: As also pointed out in the same post, it doesn't work across all browsers. Which browser did you use to test? And does your console (if you are using Chrome/Firefox) display any errors?

Comment: First of all, I don't think you should be appending the `px`s. Secondly, [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602078/javascripts-window-resizeto-isnt-working)

Comment: @JofryHS, tested in Chrome and Firefox. Console is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a web page to resize the main browser window in Chrome. JavaScript code is only permitted to resize popup windows.

You can see in w3school an example for the `resizeTo` function, used for resizing a popup:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");  // Opens a new window
}

function resizeWin() {
    myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);                             // Resizes the new window
    myWindow.focus();                                        // Sets focus to the new window
}
```

Comment: Thanks 0x... If you're sure that there is no way, then - solved.