# Changing Website View in Browser to responsive mode

Tags: javascript

I've got a Application wich offers possibilities to produce normal or responsive content.

Now I want to implement a preview Funktion so the user can test and switch automaticall between the views, like its implemented in chrome.

[image]

Just want three buttons, smartphone, tablet, desktop. Does someone have a great Idea how to do this nicely? It should work in all current browsers :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Resize Browser Window - this will give you a new viewport, which any relative width then adapts to. Use

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

(source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6709468/5909155)) no need for jquery.

Also take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

**Solution 2**: Edit the viewport itself.
As found in a 5 second search in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094906/5909155).

```
viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=YOURWIDTH');
```

Comment: yeah thats for a new window, I want it for the actual one

Comment: the W3 example is. The resizeTo method can also be called on the current window (even though it's forbidden by some browsers)