# keep ui autocomplete open at all times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the ui autocomplete: [over here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#options)

I need the autocomplete to be open at all times, so it shouldn't close when somewhere in the body is clicked. I have googled this but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

here's a working example of how to do it : http://jsfiddle.net/4pk3V/

keep your autocomplete box open by searching the same input again whenever close event  is triggered:

```
$( "#input" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,

    close : function (event, ui) {
         val = $("#comment").val();
         $("#input").autocomplete( "search", val ); //keep autocomplete open by 
         //searching the same input again
         $("#input").focus();
        return false;  
    }
});
```

Comment: Removing `$("#comment").focus();` still keeps the autocomplete open and allows the user to actually select another element.

Answer (score 42):

Hey sorry for the late response!

I feel this is a lot cleaner than keeping focus on the input and searching multiple times.

Try this...

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( "#input1" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    close : function (event, ui) {
        if (!$("ul.ui-autocomplete").is(":visible")) {
            $("ul.ui-autocomplete").show();
        }
    }
});
```

DEMO: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/AJtvJ/

Hope this helps!

Comment: So much better than performing ajax calls every time

Comment: Good solution, but what if I need to close it after a selection?

Answer (score 8):

There is also a CSS only option:

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete { display: inline-block !important; }
</style>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Monstermensch/G7YYZ/1/

---

You should also add the following code to avoid problems if the browser is resized (source: [Repositioning jQuery UI Autocomplete on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037483/repositioning-jquery-ui-autocomplete-on-browser-resize)):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#input1").autocomplete("search");
});
```

Comment: The css only option is great. I use it to prevent the autocomplete widget from being closed while I am trying to inspect it in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution:
Add the following config to `$input.autocomplete`:

```
close: function (event, ui) {
  $input.autocomplete('widget').show();
}
```

In order to close the menu you need to add a click away handler.
I found that the simplest way to do this is:

```
$input.on('blur', function () {
  $input.autocomplete('widget').hide();
});
```