# Is it possible to get HTML5 autocomplete list always open?

Tags: html, autocomplete, html-datalist

I try to create Angular 6 autocomplete with partly matching values. Is it possible to get HTML5 datalist opens always if got more then one option? At this moment it's opens only if exact match any option in the datalist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep ui autocomplete open at all times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149026/keep-ui-autocomplete-open-at-all-times)

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
<option value="Internet Explorer">
<option value="Firefox">
<option value="Chrome">
<option value="Opera">
 <option value="Safari">
 </datalist>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9   and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

</body>
</html>
```