# Jquery flash of unstyled content (IE and Chrome)

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-browser window resize event - JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery)
>   [Jquery flash of unstyled content (IE only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244544/jquery-flash-of-unstyled-content-ie-only)

I have a div (#container) where on a click event I swap out an image and replace it with a YouTube video:

```
$("#feature_content").click(function(){
                var iframe = "<iframe />";

                var url = "http://www.youtube.com/embedlink";

                 $(iframe, {
                    name: 'videoframe',
                    id: 'videoframe',
                    src: url,
                    width: '600',
                    height: '335',
                    frameborder: 0,
                    allowfullscreen: true
                }).appendTo(this);

                $(this).find('img').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});

    });
```

However, I am getting a flash of unstyled content (the iframe) BELOW the div before the video starts playing.

This is happening in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox

Comment: Thought about placing the iframe under the image and removing the img on iframe load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing somewhat, as we don't have a demonstration of the bad behaviour, but I think your problem is that the image is still taking up the space that's supposed to be occupied by the iframe.

You should use CSS `position: absolute` attributes to ensure that they both have the same relative position within the parent div.