# jQuery on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $containerHeight = $(window).height();
    if ($containerHeight <= 818) {
        $('.footer').css({
            position: 'static',
            bottom: 'auto',
            left: 'auto'
        });
    }
    if ($containerHeight > 819) {
        $('.footer').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '3px',
            left: '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

The only problem is that this only works when the browser first loads, I want `containerHeight` to also be checked when they are resizing the window?

Any ideas?

Comment: `$(window).resize(function(){...})`

Answer (score 440, accepted):

**Here's an example using jQuery, javascript and css to handle resize events.**

(css if your best bet if you're just stylizing things on resize (media queries))
http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/LAF4G/

### css

```
.footer 
{
    /* default styles applied first */
}

@media screen and (min-height: 820px) /* height >= 820 px */
{
    .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 3px;
        left: 0px;
        /* more styles */
    }
}
```

### javascript

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 820) { /* ... */ }
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1280) {  /* ... */ }
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this); //this = window
    if (win.height() >= 820) { /* ... */ }
    if (win.width() >= 1280) { /* ... */ }
});
```

### How do I stop my resize code from executing so often!?

This is the first problem you'll notice when binding to resize. The resize code gets called a LOT when the user is resizing the browser manually, and can feel pretty janky.

To limit how often your resize code is called, you can use the [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) or [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) methods from the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) & [lodash](http://lodash.com/) libraries.

- `debounce` will only execute your resize code X number of milliseconds after the LAST resize event. This is ideal when you only want to call your resize code once, after the user is done resizing the browser. It's good for updating graphs, charts and layouts that may be expensive to update every single resize event.
- `throttle` will only execute your resize code every X number of milliseconds. It "throttles" how often the code is called. This isn't used as often with resize events, but it's worth being aware of.

If you don't have underscore or lodash, you can implement a similar solution yourself:
[JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

Comment: Thx for great answer; and for debounce/throttle info; and for link to self-roll solution.

Answer (score 64):

Move your javascript into a function and then bind that function to window resize.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateContainer();
    });
});
function updateContainer() {
    var $containerHeight = $(window).height();
    if ($containerHeight <= 818) {
        $('.footer').css({
            position: 'static',
            bottom: 'auto',
            left: 'auto'
        });
    }
    if ($containerHeight > 819) {
        $('.footer').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '3px',
            left: '0px'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this solution. Only fires once the page loads and then during window resize at predefined `resizeDelay`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
   var resizeDelay = 200;
   var doResize = true;
   var resizer = function () {
      if (doResize) {

        //your code that needs to be executed goes here

        doResize = false;
      }
    };
    var resizerInterval = setInterval(resizer, resizeDelay);
    resizer();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      doResize = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: It works for me, thank you. But can you please explain why your "var resizer = function ()" gets actually fired? In my understanding, you only set the variable doResize in the $(window).resize event but do not call the function itself.

Comment: There is a call to the function: `resizer();` right after setting the interval. And because the `doResize` is set to `true`, it gets fired when document is ready.

Comment: Yes, for me it is understandable that the function is executed with document.ready. But I can't understand why the function is also executed after resizing, because in my understanding only the variable is set. For me it would only make sense if after the resize the document.ready is fired again, so that the function is started again (but that should not be the case?).

Answer (score 13):

jQuery has a resize event handler which you can attach to the window, [**.resize()**](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). So, if you put `$(window).resize(function(){/* YOUR CODE HERE */})` then your code will be run every time the window is resized.

So, what you want is to run the code after the first page load and whenever the window is resized. Therefore you should pull the code into its own function and run that function in both instances.

```
// This function positions the footer based on window size
function positionFooter(){
    var $containerHeight = $(window).height();
    if ($containerHeight <= 818) {
        $('.footer').css({
            position: 'static',
            bottom: 'auto',
            left: 'auto'
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.footer').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '3px',
            left: '0px'
        });
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    positionFooter();//run when page first loads
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    positionFooter();//run on every window resize
});
```

See: [Cross-browser window resize event - JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery)

Comment: ...or you can rewrite the document ready handler as `$(function() { $(window).resize(positionFooter).triggerHandler('resize'); });`

Answer (score 8):

Give your anonymous function a name, then:

```
$(window).on("resize", doResize);
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 6):

```js
function myResizeFunction() {
  ...
}

$(function() {
  $(window).resize(myResizeFunction).trigger('resize');
});
```

This will cause your resize handler to trigger on window resize and on document ready. Of course, you can attach your resize handler outside of the document ready handler if you want `.trigger('resize')` to run on page load instead.

**UPDATE**: Here's another option if you don't want to make use of any other third-party libraries.

This technique adds a specific class to your target element so you have the advantage of controlling the styling through CSS only (and avoiding inline styling).

It also ensures that the class is only added or removed when the actual threshold point is triggered and not on each and every resize. It will fire at *one* threshold point only: when the *height* changes from <= 818 to > 819 or vice versa and not multiple times within each region. It's not concerned with any change in *width*.

```js
function myResizeFunction() {
  var $window = $(this),
      height = Math.ceil($window.height()),
      previousHeight = $window.data('previousHeight');

  if (height !== previousHeight) {
    if (height < 819)
      previousHeight >= 819 && $('.footer').removeClass('hgte819');
    else if (!previousHeight || previousHeight < 819)
      $('.footer').addClass('hgte819');

    $window.data('previousHeight', height);
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).on('resize.optionalNamespace', myResizeFunction).triggerHandler('resize.optionalNamespace');
});
```

As an example, you might have the following as some of your CSS rules:

```css
.footer {
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  position: static;
}

.footer.hgte819 {
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: So concise and efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

can use it too

```
        function getWindowSize()
            {
                var fontSize = parseInt($("body").css("fontSize"), 10);
                var h = ($(window).height() / fontSize).toFixed(4);
                var w = ($(window).width() / fontSize).toFixed(4);              
                var size = {
                      "height": h
                     ,"width": w
                };
                return size;
            }
        function startResizeObserver()
            {
                //---------------------
                var colFunc = {
                     "f10" : function(){ alert(10); }
                    ,"f50" : function(){ alert(50); }
                    ,"f100" : function(){ alert(100); }
                    ,"f500" : function(){ alert(500); }
                    ,"f1000" : function(){ alert(1000);}
                };
                //---------------------
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    var sz = getWindowSize();
                    if(sz.width > 10){colFunc['f10']();}
                    if(sz.width > 50){colFunc['f50']();}
                    if(sz.width > 100){colFunc['f100']();}
                    if(sz.width > 500){colFunc['f500']();}
                    if(sz.width > 1000){colFunc['f1000']();}
                });
            }
        $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                startResizeObserver();
            });
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does a bit more.  You're not really offering much of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind `resize` using [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and run your code when the browser is resized. You need to also add an `else` condition to your `if` statement so that your css values toggle the old and the new, rather than just setting the new.