# jQuery Dynamically Sized margins 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

I'm working on dynamically resizing vertical margins with jQuery and I'm wonder if if how I can resolve a problem that causes the margins to resize only once when the page loads.

```
    /* PAGE SIZE */
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var WIDTH = $(window).width();
        if(WIDTH > 1420){
            $("ul#menu-content-1.menu").css("margin-top","59px");
            $("div.menu-content-container").css("margin-top","59px")
        } else if(WIDTH < 1420) {
            $("ul#menu-content-1.menu").css("margin-top","-59px");
            $("div.menu-content-container").css("margin-top","-59px");
        }
    });
```

This is my existing code. How can I fix this recurring problem so that each time the page loads and the window is resized, the margins will adjust?

Comment: It's a little difficult to diagnose the issue with a single block of JavaScript. If you set up a [reduced](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [test case](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets), maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ready()`, `.resize()` are short-cuts for using the `.bind()` function (or `.on()` in jQuery 1.7+). `.resize(function () {})` maps to `.bind('resize', function () {})`.

Here is how your code would look using `.on()` wherever possible:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

         // Stuff in here happens on ready and resize.

        var WIDTH = $(window).width();
        if(WIDTH > 1420){
            $("ul#menu-content-1.menu").css("margin-top","59px");
            $("div.menu-content-container").css("margin-top","59px")
        } else if(WIDTH < 1420) {
            $("ul#menu-content-1.menu").css("margin-top","-59px");
            $("div.menu-content-container").css("margin-top","-59px");
        }

    }).trigger('resize'); // Trigger resize handlers.       

});//ready
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you want to trigger this at some point?

On window resize possibly: [jQuery on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-execution-on-window-resize)

Also I would recommend using CSS media queries for the above:

```
ul #menu-content-1.menu {margin-top: 59px}
div.menu-content-container {margin-top:59px}

@media (max-width: 1420) 
{ 
    ul #menu-content-1.menu {margin-top: -59px}
    div.menu-content-container {margin-top: -59px}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting it in the $ (window) .load ();

```
 $(window).load(function(){
        var WIDTH = $(window).width();
        if(WIDTH > 1420){
            $("ul#menu-content-1.menu").css("margin-top","59px");
            $("div.menu-content-container").css("margin-top","59px")
        } else if(WIDTH < 1420) {
            $("ul#menu-content-1.menu").css("margin-top","-59px");
            $("div.menu-content-container").css("margin-top","-59px");
        }
    });
```