# How to restore display:block when switching @media stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web application with a left-hand side menu.  The menu is useful when the browser window is wide (e.g., desktops), but takes too much space when the window is narrow (e.g., mobile).

Using css `@media` stuff, I can make it so that if you make the browser window smaller than some resize width, it will switch to mobile mode.  In this mode, I still want the menu to be available, but for it to be hidden until the user clicks a button to bring it up.

This is easy enough, but I am running into a problem.  If the normal desktop user:

1. Switches to Mobile Mode (resizes the browser smaller than the resize width)
2. Turns the menu on (javascript to set its `display:` to `block`)
3. Turns the menu off (js to set its `display:` to `none`)
4. Switches back to Desktop Mode (resizes the browser to be wide again)

Then the menu is still using `display:none` and is invisible, even though it should always be available in desktop mode.

Here is a [working illustration of the problem](http://www.kookamara.com/js-menu-question/demo.html).

My question: is there something I can do to prevent this?  Perhaps a way to detect when the browser is switching the stylesheet it is using, and to reset the menu bar to `display:block` when desktop mode is re-entered?

### Basic HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css" media="all and (min-width: 600px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="all and (max-width: 600px)"/>
...
<div id="left"> ... menu bar ... </div>
<div id="right"> ... content ... </div>
```

### Mobile stylesheet:

```
#left { display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 100; ... }
#right { left: 0px; ... }
```

### Desktop stylesheet

```
#left { display: block; position: fixed; left: 0; ...}
#right { position: fixed; left: 170px; ...}
```

### Javascript for toggling the menu

```
function toggleLeft() { $("#left").toggle(); } // Using jQuery
```

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem I run into a fair amount myself.  I tend to use a class instead of directly hiding/showing the menu in mobile.  For example:

```
function toggleLeft() { $("#left").toggleClass("active"); }
```

Then in your CSS media queries, only make use of the .active in the mobile stylesheet.

```
#left { display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 100; ... }
#left.active { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that  your `display: block;` in your desktop.css has lower priority then direct styling by element atribute style:

```
<div id="left" style="display: none"> ... </div>
```

which is exactly what javascript's toggle() do.
The best way is to toggle class. However you can simply add `display: block !important` into your desktop.css. Styles with `!important` won't be changed by the direct styling.

Comment: Thank you -- I didn't know about `!important`.  This seems to work perfectly well.  I ended up using Jonathan's solution because it seems maybe somehow cleaner, though I can't articulate why I feel that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should maybe toggle the css using jQuery on window resize:

[jQuery on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize)

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this); //this = window
    if (win.height() >= 820) { /* toggle css or class etc */ }
    if (win.width() >= 1280) { /* ... */ }
});
```

This way when the browser is scaled up again, you can just toggle or change the class back to what it was!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `toggle()` is setting the actual `style` on the `node`, which will override the css.

You could try to add `!important` to your css so it would override the style in desktop mode, but it's a little hacky.