# Unload jQuery Mousewheel binding on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, mousewheel, unbind

I am currently using Brandon Aaron's "[jQuery Mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)"-script to invert the scrolling direction of a Page. I am very new to jQuery and would like to disable this script on mobile devices / for a resultion < 568px.

The binding of the Mousewheel is done as following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#maincontain').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Any novice help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want it to detect small screens:

```
if ($(window).width()>=568) { // or any number you like
   // load the mousewheel plugin
}
```

If what you really want is to [detect touchscreens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4817029/), that's a bit more complicated, but you can start with this:

```
if (!(('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) {
   // load the mousewheel plugin
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help! it's almost working – the only problem is: i would like this script to be disabled on desktop-devices, too, once the screen becomes < 568px. as stated, jQuery is still rocket science for me. currently, your if statement is initialized on page-load, i suppose. is it possible to disable the mousewheel script even after the screen has only been resized? thanks again!

Comment: (sorry for formulating a wrong question to begin with, as i guess i was asking for mobile devices)

Comment: There is a [`$(window).resize()` event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9828831/) you can monitor. However, you'll need to actively destroy the mousewheel plugin when the window gets too small. I would first ask yourself if this is likely to be an issue with real users of your page/site.