# Javascript & CSS Media Queries : css classes applied to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> Please READ THE QUESTION CAREFULLY

When using bootstrap, Consider the following scenario where `col-lg-6` is applied for `large` screen sizes and `col-sm-12` on small screens.

The demo markup is

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">

     <!--some content -->

 </div>
```

Rules defined in `col-sm-12` are not applied unless the screen size is `SMALL` so I want to perform some action with `jquery` when user resizes the screen and rules defined in `col-sm-12` is applicable for current element. Don't want to go with `javascript` workaround for measuring screen size!

Answer (score 1):

Write your own media queries in your css file:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .contentShown{
       display:none;
     }

    .contenthidden{
       display:block;
     }
}
```

As for preforming an action like loading new content on window resize then you have to listen for the event and when the size is the desired width call you action via ajax and load in new content:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.height() >= 820) { /* ... */ }
      if (win.width() >= 1280) { /* ... */ }
});
```

Full answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize)

Comment: I want to perform some perform some action using javascript/jquery when rules defined in specific class are applied! I have written the media queries!

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood your question. You can not prefom any action if you will not measure screenSize via javascript/jquery.  What you can do is define which elements on the page that should be visible in css. Ill edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

The bootstap website has the default breakpoints, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries. This will tell you at what sizes `col-sm-12` and `col-lg-6` are being applied.

As far as hiding and showing elements, you will have to create classes to do this and then add them to the style sheet using the media queries bootstrap uses.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jquery then use the `is()` function to check the class of the wrapper or any elements of a page

`if ($(".wrapper").is(".col-sm-12")) {
    // do an action here
  };`

My code seems pretty basic Hope it helps

Comment: Then you should used
`$(window).bind('resize', function () { 
    alert('resize');
});`

Comment: not working ! tried here at JSBin. Check out the link - https://jsbin.com/hajogenegi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's about media queries and jquery