# getting wrong offset value on window resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to  get offset top value of an element while window is resizing.

I have written this function:

```
function setPosTop() {
    var offtop = document.getElementsByClassName('cycloneslider-caption')[0].offsetTop;
    console.log('offtop ', offtop);
}
```

Its working fine on window load, but its not getting the correct value on window resize function.

I have searched and applied many options but not working correctly.

Please provide me solution / magic code regarding this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Impossible to answer like this, can you provide a fiddle / working code example? What do you mean by 'not correctly'?

Comment: can you show your event window resize handler?

Comment: do you have something like this? `$( window ).resize(function() {setPosTop();});`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize