# On load jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi I have jqgrid which on resize trigger a function so that it resizes according to window size. This function fine but I need that same function to work when the jqgrid loads
so I am calling the function like this

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
     $('#' + grid_id).setGridWidth(width, true); //Back to original width
    $('#' + grid_id).setGridWidth($('#' + div_id).width(), true); //Resized to new width as per window
    });
```

But it is not working.

The same function is called when the window is resized like this

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
            $('#' + grid_id).setGridWidth(width, true); //Back to original width
            $('#' + grid_id).setGridWidth($('#' + div_id).width(), true); //Resized to new width as per window
        }).trigger('resize');
```

And it works fine. What is wrong am I doing here.

Comment: Can You post the output of a developer console? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9828919/665159

Comment: As you're using window.load, why not use `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Comment: You might also prefer to use one of the grid events, eg `loadComplete`  http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: actually, this jqgrid is load from somewhere else in another files so I cant use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setGridWidth` method of jqGrid only **after** the grid is created.

I suppose that you need to do is probably adding the option `autowidth: true`.

If you want to implement your own custom resizing then you can do it inside of `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` event. The code could be about the following:

```
var $grid = $("#grid"),
    resizeGrid = function () {
        var newWidth = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
        $(this).jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
    };

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    resizeGrid.call($grid);
});

$grid.on("jqGridAfterLoadComplete", resizeGrid)
.jqGrid({
    // all jqGrid options
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejpn9/153/

Answer (score 0):

I allways used "DOMContentLoaded" event and It worked like a charm.

Please Try:

```
 element.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //Element loaded
  });
```

Comment: this is called from some else file and function is another file so I cant use this

Comment: @shv22 that comment doesn't make much sense tbh