# Change navigation layout on page resize without having to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation, responsive

My navigation won't show properly when I make the viewport smaller. When I refresh the page, it works. However if I make it big again, my navigation is gone. What am I missing? I tried writing the code another way but I'm not experienced enough.

I would like it to directly show it how it's supposed to be, not that I have to refresh the page when I resize my viewport.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
    $('.fa-bars').click(function() {
      $("ul").toggleClass("toggled");
      $('.dropdown').slideToggle();
    })
  }
})
```

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: auto;
    width: 35vw;
  }
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 230px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="mobileDropdown">
        <a href="index.html" title="Home"><img id="Logo" src="../Images/Logo.svg"></a>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="rectangle dropdown"><a href="ueber_mich.html">Über mich</a></li>
      <li class="rectangle dropdown"><a href="aktuell.html">Aktuell</a></li>
      <li id="AktuelleSeite" class="dropdown"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="rectangle dropdown"><a href="angebot.html">Angebot</a></li>
      <li class="rectangle dropdown"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready()` will only run once, when the document is ready. You need to add that code in the event handler for the [`resize event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) instead

Comment: You need to handle the resize event. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize

Comment: @George is correct, however it would be a much better idea to use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this instead, as they perform many times better than JS for changing styling based on window size.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem ? if so, you're requested to mark the answer as accepted and upvote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).resize()` is what you should use in this case.

**Note:** I strongly suggest to handle such issues with CSS Media queries.

But if you really have to do it with JS. Have a look at the code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fixNav() { // wrap your code in a function for later use;
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
      $('.dropdown').hide();
      $('.fa-bars').click(function() {
        $("ul").toggleClass("toggled");
        $('.dropdown').slideToggle();
      })
    }
  }
  // now call fixNav()
  fixNav();
  $(window).resize(fixNav) // call fixNav() on window resize too
})
```