# How to reset event on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building responsive menu. I want to show Menu button, when I am under 1100px, and for above i show normal horizontal menu. I first check $(window).width() and if width is less than 1100px I trigger some events, and if not then another.

My Menu button (for under 1100px) has click event. When I first have windows above 1100px (for example 1300px) and then resize for mobile, this click event does not work.

It works only when I reload my page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 1100) {
    $('.menu-button').click(function(e) {
      $('#menu-body').slideToggle();  
      $(this).parent().siblings().children().children().removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.menu-top').click(function(e) {
      $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
      $(this).siblings().addClass('active');
    });

  } else {
    $('.menu-top').mouseover(function(e) {
      $(this).parent().parent().children().children().removeClass('active');
      $(this).siblings().addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active-top');
    });

    $('.menu-point').mouseleave(function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('active-top');
      $(this).children().removeClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe do it in CSS instead of in JS?

Comment: I already do that with CSS. With media queries. Here goes just about events. When I switch / resize the browser to mobile, my events does not work anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the click/mouse event listeners only when the document finishes loading (`$(document).ready`).
This is called after the page is done loading, and after refresh.

You'll need to call this code again whenever the windows size passes the breakpoint in either direction.

[jQuery on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize)

In your case,

```
function foobar() {
    if($(window).width() < 1100) {
        $('.menu-button').click(function(e) {
            $('#menu-body').slideToggle();  
            $(this).parent().siblings().children().children().removeClass('active');
        });

        $('.menu-top').click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
            $(this).siblings().addClass('active');
        });
    } else {
        $('.menu-top').mouseover(function(e) {
            $(this).parent().parent().children().children().removeClass('active');
            $(this).siblings().addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active-top');
        });

        $('.menu-point').mouseleave(function(e) {
            $(this).removeClass('active-top');
            $(this).children().removeClass('active');
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(foobar);
$(window).on('resize', foobar);
```

Comment: I have tried that, but than my click event happens more than just one time, because the resize event happens more times.

Comment: So you need to unsubscribe the listener before resubscribing.