# display window size using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display the window size, whenever I resize my window. but I'm not able to until I refresh the window, I want to see the window size on the fly while I'm resizing the window.

```js
window.onload = init();
window.onresize = init();

function init() {
  var status = document.querySelector("#pagesize");
  status.innerHTML = "" + window.innerHeight + " " + window.innerWidth;
}
```

```css
#pagesize {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
html code:-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>window resize</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>PAGE WINDOW SIZE <span id="pagesize">NOT LOADED YET</span></p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: op has window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth at the bottom of the code...

Comment: remove the brackets here: `window.onload=init(); window.onresize=init();` should be `window.onload=init; window.onresize=init;` or else you attribute the result of the function execution (eg. `false` returned by default) to the events handlers, not the function itself (too lazy today to find the dupe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828831/jquery-on-window-resize)

Comment: This answer has a JS solution that you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828919/749622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the function to the event handler. Or even better use `addEventListener()` so you don't overwrite existing handlers. You stored the result of the `init()` function in the event handler.

```js
window.onload = init;
window.onresize = init;

/* or better use this */
//window.addEventListener('load', init);
//window.addEventListener('resize', init);

function init() {
  var status = document.querySelector("#pagesize");
  status.innerHTML = "" + window.innerHeight + " " + window.innerWidth;
}
```

```css
#pagesize {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>window resize</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>PAGE WINDOW SIZE <span id="pagesize">NOT LOADED YET</span></p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```