# How do I bottom-align grid elements in bootstrap fluid layout

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fluid layout using Twitter's bootstrap, wherein I have a row with two columns.  The first column has a lot of content, which I want to fill the span normally.  The second column just has a button and some text, which I want to bottom align relative to the cell in the first column.

Here's what I have:

```
-row-fluid-------------------------------------
+-span6----------+ +-span6----------+
|                | |short content   |
| content        | +----------------+
| that           | 
| is tall        |    
|                |
+----------------+
-----------------------------------------------
```

Here's what I want:

```
-row-fluid-------------------------------------
+-span6----------+
|                |
| content        |
| that           | 
| is tall        | +-span6----------+    
|                | |short content   |
+----------------+ +----------------+
-----------------------------------------------
```

I've seen solutions that make the first span an absolute height, and position the second span relative to it, but a solution where I didn't have to specify the absolute height of my divs would be preferred.  I'm also open to a complete rethink of how to achieve the same effect.  I'm not married to this use of the scaffolding, it just seemed to make the most sense to me.

**This layout as a fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ryansturmer/A7buv/3/

Comment: could you not add a margin-top of around 200px to your .rightspan?

Comment: Shortcut to CSS only answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14223553/259725

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/125740# (Sorry I forget which answer to which SO question this link is from.)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Please note: **for Bootstrap 4+ users, please consider [Christophe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982317/1430996)** (Bootstrap 4 introduced flexbox, which provides for a more elegant CSS-only solution). The following will work for earlier versions of Bootstrap...

---

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/bAHfj/ for a working solution.

```
//for each element that is classed as 'pull-down', set its margin-top to the difference between its own height and the height of its parent
$('.pull-down').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.css('margin-top', $this.parent().height() - $this.height())
});
```

On the plus side:

- in the spirit of [Bootstrap's existing helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#misc), I named the class `pull-down`.
- only the element that is getting "pulled down" needs to be classed, so...
- ...it's reusable for different element types (div, span, section, p, etc)
- it's fairly-well supported (all the major browsers support margin-top)

Now the bad news:

- it requires jQuery
- it's not, as-written, responsive (sorry)

Comment: for responsiveness, perhaps hook the window.resize? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969091/244811

Comment: Don't use a jQuery solution for something that could be a CSS solution. There's many reasons to avoid DOM manipulation for styling purposes.

Comment: @Archonic : what is that CSS-only solution? I would also prefer it to a JS-dependent solution. Just keep in mind OP's stipulation: "a solution where I didn't have to specify the absolute height of my divs would be preferred"

Comment: @cfx Posted a css only solution with a fiddle that doesn't require absolute heights.

Comment: On the other hand, my solution allows the user to bottom-align individual elements (giving similar behaviour to Bootstrap's `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`), without affecting siblings. Can that be done with CSS-only solution?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Changed "margin-top" to "padding-top" to make this work for sticky footer etc.

Answer (score 69):

This is an updated solution for Bootstrap 3 (should work for older versions though) that uses CSS/LESS only:

http://jsfiddle.net/silb3r/0srp42pb/11/

You set the font-size to 0 on the row (otherwise you'll end up with a pesky space between columns), then remove the column floats, set display to `inline-block`, re-set their font-size, and then `vertical-align` can be set to anything you need.

No jQuery required.

Comment: I want to keep it at middle. However in your jsfiddle when i tried "vertical-allign:middle" then it didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try setting both `div`s to `vertical-align: middle;`.

Comment: This is the only acceptable answer! @Lukas's will ignore widths on columns that don't fill a row. And DOM manipulation for styling... SMH.

Comment: Your CSS is keyed off the row (specifically, `.myrow`)...doesn't this mean you can't have one column top-aligned, one column bottom-aligned, and a third column top-aligned?

Comment: Thanks ! Works fine with Bootstrap 4.

Comment: You can replace 'last-child' by 'first-child' if you want to have the first element at the bottom and the last at the top.

Comment: This I think is the best answer and even preferable to using flexbox, since that can easily not work with fluid layours with standard BS 3 at lower resolutions.

Comment: Finally a pure design solution for bootstrap structure. Thanks !

Comment: Does not work if you want to have one of the columns `vertical-align:middle` and another on top or bottom.

Answer (score 36):

You can use flex:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-fluid {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using felx is very nice and straightforward in my opinion and I had one more advantage using "align-items: baseline" that was great with differet fonts in the different items to align.

Comment: Excellent suggestion to use flex. Simple, strait-forward, and uses Bootstrap to solve a Bootstrap problem.

Comment: Brilliant answer and works perfectly with bootstrap with no javascript / jquery needed.

Comment: Yup, add this to a regular bootstrap row and bam, it works. Beautiful. How a non-responsive, jquery solution became the top answer? We'll never know.

Comment: @LeviFuller My guess is because this solution only supports one breakpoint

Comment: In addition to using d-flex I added align-items-end to my col and my button aligned to the bottom in the grid. Was useful because I had 2 other columns with labels. Prior the button was at the top and did not align properly with the input boxes.

Answer (score 27):

You need to add some style for `span6`, smthg like that:

```
.row-fluid .span6 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
}
```

and this is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sgB3T/

Comment: I would create a specific css class instead of setting it to span6, but the table-cell strategy works well! I also had to set "display: table-row" to the containing div to have correct widths.

Comment: For Bootstrap 3 I added this rule: .row.align-bottom > [class^=col]{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: none;
} apply align-bottom to the row &lt;div class="row align-bottom"&gt;

Comment: @Martin, your rule works fine when you also set .align-bottom { display: table-row;}, however, the row alignment is off because table rows don't respect the bootstrap margin-left and margin-right: -15px......thoughts?

Comment: @AlexWhite - Put `padding-left: 0` and `padding-right: 0` on all the cols in that row.

Comment: This will ignore column widths when columns don't fill the width of a row. When using offsets for example.

Answer (score 14):

Here's also an angularjs directive to implement this functionality

```
    pullDown: function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
          var $parent = iElement.parent();
          var $parentHeight = $parent.height();
          var height = iElement.height();

          iElement.css('margin-top', $parentHeight - height);
        }
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Just set the parent to `display:flex;` and the child to `margin-top:auto`.  This will place the child content at the bottom of the parent element, assuming the parent element has a height greater than the child element.

There is no need to try and calculate a value for `margin-top` when you have a height on your parent element or another element greater than your child element of interest within your parent element.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it's short, simple, and works in any browser that supports flex. The only drawback is it breaks responsiveness.

Answer (score 5):

This is based on cfx's solution, but rather than setting the font size to zero in the parent container to remove the inter-column spaces added because of the display: inline-block and having to reset them, I simply added

```css
.row.row-align-bottom > div {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}
```

to the column divs to compensate.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the other answers here is an even more responsive version. I made changes from Ivan's version to support viewports <768px wide and to better support slow window resizes.

```
!function ($) { //ensure $ always references jQuery
    $(function () { //when dom has finished loading
        //make top text appear aligned to bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841387/how-do-i-bottom-align-grid-elements-in-bootstrap-fluid-layout
        function fixHeader() {
            //for each element that is classed as 'pull-down'
            //reset margin-top for all pull down items
            $('.pull-down').each(function () {
                $(this).css('margin-top', 0);
            });

            //set its margin-top to the difference between its own height and the height of its parent
            $('.pull-down').each(function () {
                if ($(window).innerWidth() >= 768) {
                    $(this).css('margin-top', $(this).parent().height() - $(this).height());
                }
            });
        }

        $(window).resize(function () {
            fixHeader();
        });

        fixHeader();
    });
}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks for this refinement, I've just taken it for a current project and it's working well.

Comment: Why set `margin-top` to 0, then set it again to the new value? Also, why do these things in two `each()` "loops"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't like any of those answers, my solution of the same problem was to add this:`<div>&nbsp;</div>`. So in your scheme it would look like this (more or less), no style changes were necessary in my case:

```
-row-fluid-------------------------------------
+-span6----------+ +----span6----------+
|                | | +---div---+       |
| content        | | | & nbsp; |       |
| that           | | +---------+       |
| is tall        | | +-----div--------+|   
|                | | |short content   ||
|                | | +----------------+|
+----------------+ +-------------------+
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you know the number of `&nbsp;` to add if the length of the left cell is unknown?

Answer (score -3):

```
.align-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you should try to add some info to your answer explaining why it answers the OP question