# Bottom-align grid elements in bootstrap fluid layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found in a thread a way to Bottom-align grid elements in bootstrap :

[How do I bottom-align grid elements in bootstrap fluid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841387/how-do-i-bottom-align-grid-elements-in-bootstrap-fluid-layout?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

On last anwser the guy say that I can do it this way and link to a fiddle

Link to the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/silb3r/0srp42pb/11/

I tried but I can't figure out what I did wrong, here my code :

HTML:

```
<div class="row rowMidle">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="leftTown"><img src="images/TownLeft.png" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="char1"><img src="images/char1.png" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="char2"><img src="images/char2.png" height="70%" width="70%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="char3"> <img src="images/char3.png" height="80%" width="80%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="paneau"><img src="images/EditGetElement.png" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="leftTown"><img src="images/towright.png" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
    </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rowMidle > * {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rowMidle > *:last-child {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here you can check it online, to see the issue by yourself:
http://goldiman.alwaysdata.net/

Thank you
Best regards
Goldiman

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bottom-align grid elements in bootstrap fluid layout issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626521/bottom-align-grid-elements-in-bootstrap-fluid-layout-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.row.rowMidle {
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.row.rowMidle > div > div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

remove `float:none;` from `.rowMidle > *`

Comment: Thank you, it solve a part of the problem but the elements are still not aligned on the bottom :(