# Label height on multicolumn form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On multicolumn bootstrap form with labels on top, if one of the labels is large than column size, inputs will be not aligned. See the example on http://jsfiddle.net/yynkc2zn/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form action="#">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="field1">This is large label for Field1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" placeholder="field1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="field2">Field2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field2" placeholder="field2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="field3">Field3</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field3" placeholder="field3">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="field4">Field4</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field4" placeholder="field4">
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="field5">Field5</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field5" placeholder="field5">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="field5">Field6</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field6" placeholder="field6">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've not found good solution for solve this problem. There are some standard solution using bootstrap classes?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841387/how-do-i-bottom-align-grid-elements-in-bootstrap-fluid-layout

Comment: Furthermore your columns inside your one row are greater than 12! There should be always sum up to 12

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$(function() {
  var maximum = null;
  $('label').each(function(){
    var hvalue = $(this).height();
    maximum = (hvalue > maximum) ? hvalue : maximum;
  });
  $('label').css('min-height',maximum+'px');
})
```

Get height for each label and set min-height for each label with the maximum value

http://jsfiddle.net/yynkc2zn/7