# move content to a different div on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window-resize

I have a design where on mobiles/tablets all the text is in one div but when on 'desktop' the `p` tags move to the div below it. (All divs have different background images).

Here's the markup -

```
<main>
    <div class="pane">
        <h2>A thing</h2>
        <p>This stuff needs to jump to pane-details below when around 48em</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-details">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <h2>Another thing</h2>
        <p>This stuff needs to jump to pane-details below when around 48em</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-details">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <h2>A third thing</h2> 
        <p>This stuff needs to jump to pane-details below when around 48em</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-details">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <h2>A fourth thing</h2>
        <p>This stuff needs to jump to pane-details below when around 48em</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-details">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <h2>The last thing</h2>
        <p>This stuff needs to jump to pane-details below when around 48em</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-details">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</main>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/sturobson/pen/aCqDc

So, when the page hits 48em (768px) the `<p>` in `.pane` needs to drop down into the following `.pane-details`

How do I do this without duplicating the content and nastily resorting to `display: none;`.

Comment: You can use jQuery for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery):

```
$(window).on('resize'), function() {
    if ($(window).width()<768) {
        // move the element
    } else {
        // move it back
    };
}).trigger('resize'); // force it to run on load
```

However, you can probably solve this with pure CSS if you rethink your HTML layout a little.

Comment: +1 for the `.trigger('resize');` didn't think of that at first.