# How do I disable jQuery function when screen size is less than 480px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, positioning, fixed

i have an upload form that is fixed to the top and follows with my scrolling. Now I want to disable this function when it's viewed on a phone.

Here is my script code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 430 && $(window).width() > 480) {
        $('#formwrap').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#formwrap').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: If `fixed` class is used for styling purpose only, you should use instead CSS3 media query

Answer (score 1):

use `.resize()` instead:

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    ............

}).resize(); //<----this will be fired when dom gets ready.
```

See `.scroll()` event looks for scroll but in your case you have to use `.resize()` because you want to enable/disable some function on basis of screen size and don't forget to trigger that as i mentioned in the answer or you can do.

```
$(window).resize(); // or
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need $(window)[.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(window).resize(function () {.. });
```

Read [Cross-browser window resize event - JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery

```
$(window).resize(function () {

//Your function

.. }).resize();;
```

In CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

    #formwrap{display:none;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
if(screen.width>=480)
{
    $('#formwrap').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    $('#formwrap').removeClass('fixed');
}
```