# Making dynamically created multiple SVG responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, responsive

I've created svg elements for titles. I dynamically create these elements with jQuery. I want to use this element in different places and I want them to be responsive. When I use $(window).resize function, browser gets stuck.

Here is my code:

```js
function widgetTitle() {
    $(".title-svg").each(function(i, item) {
        item = $(item);
        $(".svgWidget", item).css("width", item.width() + 17);

        var a = item.outerWidth() + 17;
        var constantPoint1 = "0.83 0.56 15.83 22.56 ";
        var constantPoint2 = " 22.56 ";
        var constantPoint3 = " 50.56";

        var changePoint = a - 2;

        var points = constantPoint1 + changePoint + constantPoint2 + changePoint + constantPoint3;
        var viewBox = "0 0 " + a + " 50.56";

        $(".svgWidget polyline", item).attr("points", points);
        $(".svgWidget", item).attr("viewBox", viewBox);
    });
}

widgetTitle();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 80%; position: relative;margin-bottom: 50px">
    <div class="title-svg" style="width: 100%;position: absolute;top: 10px;">
        <svg class="svgWidget" data-name="svgWidget" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <linearGradient id="firstGradient" x="100%" y="100%">
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="yellow">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;teal;purple;orange;red" dur="10s" from="0"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
     <stop offset=100 stop-color="purple">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color"
               values="lightblue;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;lightblue" dur="10s" from="0%"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <g style="opacity: 0.38" stroke="url(#firstGradient)">
     <polyline style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 1px"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="width: 10%: position: relative;">
    <div class="title-svg" style="width: 100%;position: absolute;top: 10px;">
        <svg class="svgWidget" data-name="svgWidget" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <linearGradient id="firstGradient" x="100%" y="100%">
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="yellow">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;teal;purple;orange;red" dur="10s" from="0"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
     <stop offset=100 stop-color="purple">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color"
               values="lightblue;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;lightblue" dur="10s" from="0%"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <g style="opacity: 0.38" stroke="url(#firstGradient)">
     <polyline style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 1px"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it did not make my elements responsive.

---

SOLVED THE PROBLEM WITH THIS CODE:

```js
function widgetTitle() {
    $(".title-svg").each(function(i, item) {
        item = $(item);
        //$(".svgWidget", item).css("width", item.width()+17);

        var a = item.outerWidth() - 2;
        var constantPoint1 = "0.83 0.56 15.83 22.56 ";
        var constantPoint2 = " 22.56 ";
        var constantPoint3 = " 50.56";

        var changePoint = a;

        var points = constantPoint1 + changePoint + constantPoint2 + changePoint + constantPoint3;
        var viewBox = "0 0 " + a + " 50.56";

        $(".svgWidget polyline", item).attr("points", points);
        $(".svgWidget", item).attr("viewbox", viewBox);
    });
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    widgetTitle();
});

widgetTitle();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you would try responsive using JQuery rather than managing this in CSS? Did that not work?

Comment: Because i want to use svg with animated background.

Comment: `attr("viewbox", viewBox)` should be `attr("viewBox", viewBox)`

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, as noted in the answer, jQuery v2 converts `.attr("viewBox", viewBox)` to lowercase. To set a valid attribute, either use jQuery v3, or `.get(0).setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox)` must be used.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not set an absolute width for the svg elements. If you need something different than 100%, use relative units like `%` or `vw`.
2. With jQuery, you have a problem: it is a HTML framework that does not support XML syntax for SVG [prior to version 3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2910). While you try to set the `viewBox` attribute, jQuery converts that to `viewbox` in lowercase, which does not work since SVG is case-sensitive. Either use the pure js syntax instead, or use jQuery in version 3 or later.
3. There is  syntax error in the outer div for the second svg

```js
function widgetTitle() {
 $(".title-svg").each(function(i, item) {
  item = $(item);
  // only need this for values other than 100%
  // $(".svgWidget", item).css("width", "100%");

  var a = item.outerWidth() + 17;
  var constantPoint1 = "0.83 0.56 15.83 22.56 ";
  var constantPoint2 = " 22.56 ";
  var constantPoint3 = " 50.56";

  var changePoint = a-2;

  var points = constantPoint1 + changePoint + constantPoint2 + changePoint + constantPoint3;
  var viewBox = "0 0 " + a + " 50.56";

  $(".svgWidget polyline", item).attr("points", points);
  $(".svgWidget", item).get(0).setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
 });
}

widgetTitle();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 80%; position: relative;margin-bottom: 50px">
    <div class="title-svg" style="width: 100%;position: absolute;top: 10px;">
   <svg class="svgWidget" data-name="svgWidget" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <linearGradient id="firstGradient" x="100%" y="100%">
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="yellow">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;teal;purple;orange;red" dur="10s" from="0"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
     <stop offset=100 stop-color="purple">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color"
               values="lightblue;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;lightblue" dur="10s" from="0%"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <g style="opacity: 0.38" stroke="url(#firstGradient)">
     <polyline style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 1px"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="width: 10%; position: relative;">
    <div class="title-svg" style="width: 100%;position: absolute;top: 10px;">
   <svg class="svgWidget" data-name="svgWidget" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <linearGradient id="firstGradient" x="100%" y="100%">
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="yellow">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;teal;purple;orange;red" dur="10s" from="0"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
     <stop offset=100 stop-color="purple">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color"
               values="lightblue;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;lightblue" dur="10s" from="0%"
               to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <g style="opacity: 0.38" stroke="url(#firstGradient)">
     <polyline style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 1px"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I can't tell you is whether your vertical positioning is what you intended. The `.title-svg` divs are absolutely positioned, so the outer divs have a height of zero. As a consequence the `<div style="clear:both"></div>` has no effect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will consider the recommendations. I think you misunderstand what I want to do. I just want SVG to be responsive. I want to run the function for all elements, not just one element

https://image.prntscr.com/image/b3AJcRt3RvGPpTOjNmaFmg.png

Comment: That would mean to re-run function `widgetTitle()` on every resize, wouldn't it? (Do not forget to throttle or [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery#36695070).)